# why does python inspect.isclass think an instance is a class?

Tags: python, introspection

Given the following module:

```
class Dummy(dict):
    def __init__(self, data):
        for key, value in data.iteritems():
            self.__setattr__(key, value)

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return self.get(attr, None)
    __setattr__=dict.__setitem__
    __delattr__=dict.__delitem__


foo=Dummy({"one":1, "two":2})
```

why does `foo` show up in the output of `inspect.getmembers(..., predicate=inspect.isclass)`?

```
$ python2.5
Python 2.5.2 (r252:60911, Aug 28 2008, 13:13:37) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20071124 (Red Hat 4.1.2-42)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import junk
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getmembers(junk, predicate=inspect.isclass)
[('Dummy', <class 'junk.Dummy'>), ('foo', {'two': 2, 'one': 1})]
>>> inspect.isclass(junk.foo)
True
```

I expected that `inspect` would only return `Dummy` since that is the only class definition in the module. Apparently, though, junk.foo is a class in the eyes of the inspect module. Why is that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Prior to Python v2.7, `inspect.isclass` naively assumed anything with a `__bases__` attribute must be a class.

`Dummy`'s `__getattr__` makes `Dummy` instances appear to have *every* attribute (with a value of `None`).

Therefore, to `inspect.isclass`, `foo` appears to be a class.

Note: [`__getattr__` should raise`AttributeError` when asked for an attribute it does not know about.](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) (This is very different than returning `None`.)

Comment: In particular the lack of `AttributeError` which will cause truly stupendously __horrible__ bugs.

Comment: Thank you. Your explanation makes complete sense.

Answer (score 6):

First if all great answer Jon-Eric i just wanted to add some stuff:

if you do in ipython (what a great tool):

```
%psource inspect.isclass
```

you will get:

```
return isinstance(object, types.ClassType) or hasattr(object, '__bases__')
```

which what Jon-Eric said.

but i guess that you use python < 2.6 and this bug was already fixed, this is the code of inspect.isclass() in python2.7:

```
return isinstance(object, (type, types.ClassType))
```

Comment: Excellent point! I *was* looking at the v2.6 source. I edited my answer to indicate that `__bases__` is no longer used in v2.7+.