# How to check if an object is a class

Tags: python, matlab, class

I have a piece of code that I need to translate from python to matlab. I'm getting stuck with the `isclass()` method in the python code:

```
inspect.isclass(object)
```

As far as I know, this checks whether or not the object is a class and returns true or false accordingly.

Is there a way to do this in matlab?

The matlab `isa` function seems like it would be a good fit, but it doesn't seem to be able to check for classes.

Comment: What kind of  class do you want to check for? Everything is a class, whether that class is `double` or `table` or `myCustomObject`... The `isa` function lets you check for a specific class

Comment: @Wolfie I need to check if something is a class or an object. I just realized I can use isobject to check it instead

Comment: "Is a class or an object"? I think nomenclature is a bit confused here. A value can never be "a class", it can be an object of a specific class. `isobject` will tell you if the value is of a custom class (a.k.a. user-defined class). There is also a `isdouble`, `ischar`, `isstring`, `iscell`, `isstruct`, etc. `class` returns the name of the value's class (i.e. the type of the value), and `isa` compares `class` to a given string.

Comment: Whatever you're doing, you're probably doing it wrong. You shouldn't need to be guessing about what you've got! Downcasting is a code smell.

Comment: Added the Python tag because it seems like you actually need to understand what `instance.isclass` is doing (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081819/why-does-python-inspect-isclass-think-an-instance-is-a-class) before trying to translate. Please [edit] your question to include your Python version, the linked question suggests the behaviour of that function changed at some point.

Comment: @Chuck MATLAB is a duck-typed language, you sometimes need to check the types of the inputs to a function.

Answer (score 0):

**If** you are trying to check whether a variable is in a class, try the isa function and pass 'class' as the type.

```
bol = isa(x, 'class');
```

**If** you are trying to check whether something is a classs, try the isa function and pass 'meta.class' as the type.

```
bol = isa(x,'meta.class');
```

Comment: What does this do? I've tried it with `x` a user-class object, and it returns False.

Comment: Right. This checks if a variable x is in any other class. You want to know if x is a class? I will update my answer.

Comment: I think OP wants the `isobject` function. I'm just curious about this answer. `isa(x,'meta.class')` returns false for me, and `isa(?x,'meta.class')` returns true, no matter what `x` is.

Comment: As far as I can tell, `isa(a,b)` is the same as `strcmp(class(a),b)`. This is why I'm curious about what you write here, it's new to me. I'm trying  to get it to work, but failing. :/

Comment: You are likely right about isobject.

Comment: I am investigating the issue you are mentioning with my colleagues. From the doc on isa: If A is an object, then isa returns 1 if the class of A, or any superclass of A, belongs to the specified category.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251118/discussion-between-iohans-and-cris-luengo).